# How to use $_POST to get input values on the same page

Tags: php, post, send

I know that this question was repeated a lot, but I searched a lot of topics and tried many codes without result.

First, I get the row number to be deleted from another page , here is no problem.

```
> if(!empty($_GET["del"])){ 
  include("config.php"); $id
> =$_GET["del"];     
> 
> echo ' <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a"> <li><p
> style="background-color: #FF0000; color:#ffffff" align="center"><font
> size="3" >Will it be permanently deleted?</font></p></li> </ul> ';    
> $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM payment where id='$id'");
> 
> ?>
> 
> <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-secondary">
> 
> 
> <table class="table table-hover">
>     <thead>
>   
>       <tr class="table-active">
>             <th scope="row">name</th>
>             <td>amount</td>
>                        
>         </tr>
>  
>     </thead>
>     <tbody>
> 
> <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { echo "<tr>"; echo
> "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>"; echo "<td>" . $row['amount'] .
> "</td>"; echo "</tr>"; } echo "</tbody>"; echo "</table>"; echo
> "</div>";
> 
> 
> mysqli_close($con);
> 
> ?>
> 
> <form action="pay.php" method="post" data-ajax='false'>
> 
> <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<? echo $id;?>" />
> <center><input type="submit" name="del" id="del" value="Delete"  />
> </center> </form>
> 
> 
> <button onclick="goBack()">Back</button> <script> function goBack() {
>     window.history.back(); } </script>
```

here the code is not work :

```
if(isset($_POST['del'])){

$id = $_POST['id'];

$sql = "DELETE FROM payment WHERE id='$id'";


    if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo '<p style="background-color: #00d855; color:#ffffff">Deletion successful</p>';
    } else {
        echo "Error deleting record: " . $con->error;
    }

    $con->close();

}
```

The codes here are all on one page pay.php.

Any Help?

Comment: use if(isset($_GET['del'])){

$id = $_GET['id'];}

Comment: thank you but i not like show any value in page url

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing as to whether you want to delete a row or get input values on the same page. I'm assuming since you've written that there is no problem with row deletion, you want to know how to input values from say a form on the same page.

Suppose you have a form with `method = "post"` then you can use the following code for any element with name say `name = "myelement"` :

```
<p>My element is: <?php echo $_POST['myelement']; ?> .</p>
```

I must say I can't clearly understand your question so I hope this is what you were looking for. If it isn't, reply to this and I'll try to help you out.

Comment: Thank you for your interest ,

On another page where rows are displayed, the user can click the delete icon for each row.

When the user clicks the delete icon, the row number is sent to pay.php page, and here the value was received without a problem.

But I do not want to delete directly, i displayed the data for Confirm Delete when user click button  delete.
This is on the same page as the row number received.

Comment: @rcweb use `javascript confirm();`

Comment: You can use inline javascript code for this, you can add the following code inside your button tag: ` onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" `

Comment: Thanku you brondibur Good solution,
I added the code to the delete button and it shows the confirmation message.
but how do I know user input and where do I put the delete code?

Comment: Put the delete code in your php file. And I mentioned the code to display user input in my original answer. Accept my answer if you think its helpful.

Comment: but to delete row from my db need to make that in php not in javascript